# iPhone app icon background color change

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

How to change iPhone app icon background color change.[See the link image](https://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Apple-allow-transparent-iOS-icons-like-OS-X).

In this image i want to clear the background color.

Comment: you can't handle this

Comment: You can't, Apple doesn't allow it.

Comment: ok thanks for your responsible reply. If i set image with background this problem won't come right?.

Answer (score 9):

You cant make transparent icon for Apple Device.

Check this Appicon Related Guidlines on apple's website .

[Appicons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html)

[image]